# An error occurred while signing

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, clickonce, assembly-signing

I maintain a large WPF application which I inherited from another developer. I use ClickOnce to publish it. Suddenly, today I got an error message:
Error   2   Cannot publish because a project failed to build.       1   1
Error   3   An error occurred while signing: Failed to sign bin\Debug\app.publish\setup.exe. SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.

I do have a file called SomeName.snk, which is referred in project settings, Signing tab. I have no idea what happened today that caused the problem.
I use VS 2012.

Comment: How did you get the full description of the error?
I also use ClickOnce and Publish directly from within VS2019. I only get "An error occurred while signing: Failed to sign bin\Release\app.publish\\setup.exe." And my problem is probably not the due to a given certificate, as the same certificate works to sign the same project from other computers, and I also get the same error when using freshly generated test certificates. I never had any problem until today, for no apparent reason.

Comment: @Ama Sorry, I don't remember. It was many years ago...

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I'd check whether the certificate expired. Most (all?) certs have an expiration date.

Comment: I tried all the solutions provided here including your but none worked!

Answer (score 236):

Go to main project **properties** > **Signing** > If the expiration date is over > click on **Create Test Certificate**, password is not mandatory, and you're done.

Comment: This is the fix for the problem.

Comment: I wonder why this feature is there in VS. and how can I dismiss it while creating my application

Comment: @Hassanation, you can dismiss this feature by unchecking the checkbox "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" in the Signing section of the properties box mentioned by Antoine.

Answer (score 6):

I got this problem installing visual c++ on top of a VS2017 .net install.  I solved it by unchecking Properties -> Security -> Enable ClickOnce security settings.

It then created an app.manifest file.  After that the error went away.  Interestingly enough, I checked it again to see what would happen and the problem did not come back.

Answer (score 5):

Did you check for the certificate?

[View or manage your certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-view-certificates-with-the-mmc-snap-in)

You can use the MMC Snap In or Internet Explorer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18478108)

Comment: @VadimMartynov The link is already dead.  I will find a good link or delete.

Answer (score 5):

Go to main project properties > Signing >  Select from Store...
Click certificate properties
And install certificate

Answer (score 5):

Go to Main project (Startup Project) and right click > properties 
Then go to Signing
Then unchecked "Sign the ClickOnce manifests"
It's work for me.

Answer (score 4):

This happens mostly if your certificate for that particular project has expired or has some issues.

Right Click Project -> Properties -> Signing Tab -> More Details button -> Shows your certificate details. Check if your certificate has expired

> ***Ways to Fix***

**1. Un-check the "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" and try**

**2. Extend the Certificate by creating a Test Certificate (If your certificate is expired)**

- Hit "**Create Test Certificate...**" button
- Enter your credentials (Not mandatory)
- Save

**3. Re-validate your existing certificate (If your certificate is not expired)**

- Hit "Select from file" button and use your existing key file (eg. .pfx)

OR

- Hit "Select from Store" button and select from the available options

> **Tip:** If you still face issues building the project. Just restart your
>   Visual Studio.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue and I was able to solve it by removing or changing the timestamp server URL. After removing that, the project was able to build successfully.

[image]

Comment: http://timestamp.sectigo.com seem indeed to be problematic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62161135/signersign-failed-2146869243-0x80096005

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the problem today. In my particular case, it was caused by this [Microsoft Windows Update](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/advisory/2661254).

I uninstalled that update and publish began working as it always had. This is only a temporary work around and means you should probably regenerate your keys/certificates.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the cert was not expired and none of the other solutions worked (restarting VS, using a temp test cert, restarting computer, etc.)

The issue was resolved by **deleting my output directory and rebuilding**.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Clean sorted it for me.
Build - Clean Solution

Answer (score 0):

In my situation I had many projects in the solution, so I browsed to the non-startup project and:

Go to main project **properties** > **Signing** > uncheck the **Sign the ClickOnce** option
*Using Visual Studio 2019*